# Text grabbing in cc illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, creative-cloud, cc-2015

I can't grab text from just anywhere, I have to specifically click the text line or bounding box, is this new to cc illustrator or is there a setting for this?

example, there is a letter "B" in size 60 pt font, I am not able to click on the "B" itself, I have to find the line it sits on or its bounding box. Just gets tricky when there are so many type boxes in a design...thanks

Comment: Can you give us some visual examples?

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with the font itself – it may have strange line height or something

Comment: Or maybe you have a effect on top of the object and the actual object is much smaller than what the effect lets you believe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the setting is "Type Object Selection by Path Only" under the Type tab in Preferences.
If that box is checked it will behave the way you are describing.

[image: Path Only]